# Is this discretized positive-definite function positive-definite?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> A positive-definite function of a real variable $x$ is a complex-valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that for any real numbers $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ the $n \times n$ matrix
> $$
> A=\left(a_{i j}\right)_{i, j=1}^{n}, \quad a_{i j}=f\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)
> $$
>
> is positive semi-definite (which requires $A$ to be Hermitian; therefore $f(-x)$ is the complex conjugate of $f(x)$ ).

The sinc function is a [positive definite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function). This is true because it is the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-2,2]}$ which is a positive function.Would the following discretized version of this function (the function in green) still be positive definite as well? Here is my attempt at the proof:

Let $\hat f$ be the discretized sinc function. Fix $x_1,\dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. If the points all exist in separate bins, then the matrix $A$ is positive semi-definite by the positive-definiteness of the sinc function. Assume two points are in the same bin but are not equal. Then this is equivalent to choosing the same point twice and $A$ will still be semi-definite. By induction, the discretized function $\hat f$ is positive-definite.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you were more precise about what you mean by discretising a function. Do you interpolate linearly in between or do you set it to be a constant in between? On the other hand, if you just care about positive definiteness as a map from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ it is trivially true I think.